# How to create a transparent Material 3 NavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make my NavigationBar transparent. I have tried `extendBody: true` on `Scafold` with `surfaceTintColor=Colors.transparent` to the `NavigationBar` widget, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the document, SurfaceTintColor is the color of the surface tint overlay applied to the app bar's background color to indicate elevation.

If you want to make the AppBar transparent, just use the property backgroundColor instead.

```dart
Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // To make appBar transparent
        
        /// This is not necessary. You can play around 
        /// to see surfaceTintColor when the AppBar is transaprent
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.redAccent,
        elevation: 3,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
),
```

It is also applied to NavigationBar

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.amber, // not neccessary
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        destinations: [
          Icon(Icons.book, color: Colors.blue,),
          Icon(Icons.map, color: Colors.blue,),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle and ColoredBox to make NavigationBar become transparent.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
);
return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: ColoredBox(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          label: 'Settings',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
...
```

It work on Android and Web.

Comment: This code makes transparet the navigation system bar, i want the **NavigationBar widget**